# create a np.array in a simpler way, and transferring to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, export-to-csv

I am looking for a simpler code to create the following array:

```
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [2. 1. 1.]
 [3. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [1. 2. 1.]
 [2. 2. 1.]
 [3. 2. 1.]
 [4. 2. 1.]
 [1. 3. 1.]
 [2. 3. 1.]
 [3. 3. 1.]
 [4. 3. 1.]
 [1. 1. 2.]
 [2. 1. 2.]
 [3. 1. 2.]
 [4. 1. 2.]
 [1. 2. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2.]
 [3. 2. 2.]
 [4. 2. 2.]
 [1. 3. 2.]
 [2. 3. 2.]
 [3. 3. 2.]
 [4. 3. 2.]]
```

I have written the following code to generate that, but definitely, it is not a good one.

```
import numpy as np

t1 = np.array([])
t2 = np.array([])

# creating the i column

for k in range (1,3):
    for j in range(1,4):
        x = np.array(list(range(1, 5)))
        y = np.append(t1, x)
        t1 = y

# creating the j column

for k in range(1,3):
    x = np.array(list(range(1, 4)))
    y = np.repeat(x, 4)
    t2 = np.append(t2, y)

# creating the k column

x = np.array(list(range(1, 3)))
t3 = np.repeat(x, 3*4)
new = np.transpose(np.vstack((t1, t2, t3)))
```

Also, in the next step I want to export it to a csv file in a way that these numbers goes there in this shape ( I mean my first column in csv file includes: 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3 and so on for the next two columns)
I tried to use `numpy.savetxt()` but it seems it only works for 1D and 2D arrays.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `np.arange(1,4)`.  list append is faster than `np.append`. `np.stack` with `axis=1` may be easier than the `vstack `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) fits your use-case perfectly:

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd

X = sorted(list(product([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3], [1,2])), key=lambda x: (x[2], x[1], x[0]))

pd.DataFrame(X).to_csv('output.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1], [4, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [2, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [4, 2, 1], [1, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1], [3, 3, 1], [4, 3, 1], [1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [4, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 2], [4, 2, 2], [1, 3, 2], [2, 3, 2], [3, 3, 2], [4, 3, 2]]
```

Comment: You can just use `list(product([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3], [1,2]))` instead of `[list(x) for x in list(product([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3], [1,2]))]`

Comment: @teepee The OP's needs sub-lists, without the list(x) it would give tuples!

Comment: thanks for your comments, this combination is not the same as mine.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have a list of lists or a list of tuples so long as you are converting it via `np.array` or `pd.DataFrame` anyway. It's just an extra step. You don't even need to create a list either; you can just use the generator to create the array like: `np.array(product([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3], [1,2]))`

Comment: @Peyman I have edited the answer to fix the order. It needed an appropriate sorting for it.

Comment: @teepee Sure, didnt realize he needed to export to csv. Edited the answer for it

Comment: Sure, just I dont understand when I use your code it gives me a reverse answer like this: [(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 2), (4, 1, 1), (4, 1, 2), (4, 2, 1), (4, 2, 2), (4, 3, 1), (4, 3, 2)]

Comment: @Peyman I tried it locally and works as you expected. Please copy the right code and try again.

Comment: @SerialLazer Thank you very much. It is in the right order now.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `itertools` module to create the array and then use `pandas` to easily export it to a csv file:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

# create the array of all combinations you showed
arr = list(itertools.product([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3], [1,2]))

# output the array to a csv file:
df = pd.DataFrame(arr).to_csv('filename.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. The way for exporting to csv worked very well but the produced combination is not right.

Answer (score 0):

While `itertools.product` may be the best (I'd also like to explore using `np.meshgrid`), we can streamline your code.

First make 3 lists with list comprehension.  `np.append` is slow when used repeatedly.  List append is better, but list comprehension is more compact.

```
In [94]: t1 = [np.arange(1,5) for k in range(2) for j in range(3)]
    ...: t2 = [np.repeat(np.arange(1,4),4) for k in range(2)]
    ...: t3 = np.repeat(np.arange(1,3), 3*4)
```

Now look at the results. The values are there, but not in quite the right shape.

```
In [95]: t1
Out[95]: 
[array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 4])]
In [96]: t2
Out[96]: 
[array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]),
 array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])]
In [97]: t3
Out[97]: 
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2])
```

But we can flatten them.  `np.ravel` will convert the list to array and flatten it.

```
In [98]: np.ravel(t1)
Out[98]: 
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2,
       3, 4])
```

Now we can join them with `stack`.  This is like `vstack` but let's control the join axis.

```
In [99]: np.stack((np.ravel(t1), np.ravel(t2), t3), axis=1)
Out[99]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [3, 1, 1],
       [4, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [3, 2, 1],
       [4, 2, 1],
       [1, 3, 1],
       ...
       [3, 3, 2],
       [4, 3, 2]])
```

Since it is 2d, `savetxt` does just fine:

```
In [100]: np.savetxt('test', Out[99], fmt='%5d')
In [101]: cat test
    1     1     1
    2     1     1
    3     1     1
    4     1     1
    1     2     1
   ...
```

===

`itertools.product` generates the right tuples, but the order is reversed:

```
In [108]: alist = list(itertools.product(range(1,3), range(1,4), range(1,5)))
In [109]: alist
Out[109]: 
[(1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (1, 1, 3),
 (1, 1, 4),
 ...
 (2, 2, 4),
 (2, 3, 1),
 (2, 3, 2),
 (2, 3, 3),
 (2, 3, 4)]
```

But that's easily changed when we make an array:

```
In [110]: np.array(alist)[:,::-1]
Out[110]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [3, 1, 1],
       [4, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 1],
       ...
       [4, 2, 2],
       [1, 3, 2],
       [2, 3, 2],
       [3, 3, 2],
       [4, 3, 2]])
```

===

Another option - `meshgrid`:

```
In [111]: x,y,z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(1,3), np.arange(1,4), np.arange(1,5), indexing='ij')
In [112]: x.shape
Out[112]: (2, 3, 4)
In [113]: y.shape
Out[113]: (2, 3, 4)
In [114]: x.ravel()
Out[114]: 
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2])
In [115]: y.ravel()
Out[115]: 
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3,
       3, 3])
In [116]: z.ravel()
Out[116]: 
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2,
       3, 4])
In [117]: np.stack([z.ravel(), y.ravel(), x.ravel()], axis=1)
Out[117]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [3, 1, 1],
       [4, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 1],
       ....
```

Another way to combine the 3 arrays:

```
np.stack((z,y,x), axis=3).reshape(-1,3)
```

The `stack` step produces a (2, 3, 4, 3) array.

===

Another method (without explanation):

```
arr = np.mgrid[1:3, 1:4, 1:5]
arr.transpose(1,2,3,0).reshape(-1,3)[:,::-1]
```